# Unable to use | character in AzureFunctionApp appSettings:

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-functions

I am setting a load of appSettings in my `AzureFunctionApp@1` deployment task - but whenever I try to put each on a new line using the  `|` character I get the error:

`##[error]Error: Failed to update App service '{{functionName}}' application settings. Error: BadRequest - Parameter name cannot be empty. (CODE: 400)`

The output above that seems to show that it has indeed built the JSON with an empty parameter name. But I don't know why? I've tested with the values on separate lines, and still in a single line, so neither of these work:

```
appSettings: |
  '-Values:Setting1 "$(SettingVal1)"
  -Values:Setting2 "$(SettingVal2)"'
```

```
appSettings: |
  '-Value:Setting1 "$(SettingVal1)" -Values:Setting2 "$(SettingVal2)"'
```

But this does:

```
appSettings: '-Value:Setting1 "$(SettingVal1)" -Values:Setting2 "$(SettingVal2)"'
```

I've also tried without the `'` - but that made no difference either.

Comment: Relevant github thread for you here.  https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7799

Comment: Try Using like Key-value pair -- ```yaml
appSettings: |
[ {  Value:Setting1 "$(SettingVal1)" }, 
 { Values:Setting2 "$(SettingVal2)" } ]

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft yes, I had read that, thanks.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT I discovered that it should accept a multi-line json input - but that becomes more verbose, because I think each line also needs a 'slotsetting'. TBH I think that is the only way to get close to what I was looking for, though 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiline JSON doesn't work with the `AzureFunctionApp@1` task's `appSettings` parameter (for some reason).

If you try to use the multiline JSON `appSettings` with the `AzureFunctionApp@1` task, you will get an error:  `BadRequest - Parameter name cannot be empty. (CODE: 400)`

To use the multiline JSON `appSettings`, you need to use a separate `AzureAppServiceSettings@1` task - as mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-settings?view=azure-devops).

I can confirm this works after the `AzureFunctionApp@1` task. So my pipeline now has:

```
steps:
...
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: Deploy the Function App
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: "${{parameters.AppAzureSubscription}}"
    appName: "${{parameters.functionAppName}}"
    package: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip"

- task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
  displayName: Update app settings
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: "${{parameters.AppAzureSubscription}}"
    appName: "${{parameters.functionAppName}}"
    appSettings: |
      [
        {
          "name": "Values:DbConnectionString",
          "value": "$(DbConnectionString)",
          "slotSetting": false
        },
...
      ]
```

Comment: I have already referred the same document which you provided, in the above comment!

Comment: I can confirm that as of July 2023, this is still the best way to configure app settings, even with the `AzureFunctionApp@2` task.

Answer (score 1):

As per your feedback - Converting my comment as an answer, also tried locally in my system.

**Multi-line json** input works for setting the multiple values in the app settings as this is the closest way.

```yaml
appSettings: |
     [
       {
         "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
         "value": "$(Key)",
         "slotSetting": false
       },
       {
         "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME",
         "value": "$(DB_Name)", 
         "slotSetting": false
       }
     ]
```

Comment: Not quite - your example doesn't work because it has the | and the JSON on one line - and that isn't valid JSON. I can't find the doc where it listed the way of using the JSON format at the moment...

Comment: Please check this MSFT documentation about Json Syntax on app settings - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-settings?view=azure-devops

Comment: No, this just doesn't work, unfortunately :( `Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {"":"[\n  {\n    \"name\": \"VarName\",\n    \"value\": \"Variable Value\",\n    \"slotSetting\": false\n  }\n]"}
##[error]Error: Failed to update App service 'serviceName' application settings. Error: BadRequest - Parameter name cannot be empty. (CODE: 400)`